# Bash/ksh substring removal

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

As per documentation:

```
${string#substring}   # strip shortest match
${string##substring}  # strip longest match
```

However, while testing I get:

```
$ string="abcABC123ABCabc"
$ echo ${string#a*C}
123ABCabc
$ echo ${string##a*C}
abc
```

so far worked as expected, however...

```
$ echo ${string#B*c}
abcABC123ABCabc
$ echo ${string##B*c}
abcABC123ABCabc
```

I would expect that the 3rd `echo` have returned `abcABC123A` (stripping away the shortest match) and the 4th would return `abcA`

What is wrong there?

Comment: The `#` variants match the beginning of the string (prefix). In examples 3 and 4 you want to match the end of the string (suffix) which suggests you want `%` and `%%` instead.

Comment: @jqurious not sure if I completely understood ... what I read is that `#` would strip _"the shortest match, starting the search from the beginning"_ and `%` would strip _"the shortest match, starting the search from the end"_ of the string. Is this wrong?

Comment: Do you know regex? The are similar to anchoring the match with `^` and `$` e.g. example 3 is like `"abcABC123ABCabc" =~ "^B.*?c"` which doesn't match. whereas with `%` it's like `"abcABC123ABCabc" =~ "B.*?c$"`

Comment: Got it, tkx! ... My previous (and wrong) understanding was that either `#` or `%` would strip off the shortest match (starting the search from the beginning or end of the string), but not necessarily anchoring the beginning or end of the string. I thought it would pick the match at any part of the string. Thanks for clarify it.

Comment: The words for what you thought it said would be "first" or "last" match.

Comment: @jqurious, ...well, having _quoted_ the strings on the right-hand side above they aren't treated as regexes but as literal exact content. The comment above makes its point properly, but `re='^B.*?c'; [[ "abcABC123ABCabc" =~ $re ]]` is a more pedantically-correct comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${var#prefix}` and `${var##prefix}` are anchored to the beginning of the string.

`${var%suffix}` and `${var%%suffix}` are anchored to the end of a string.

If you want an unanchored replacement, then you should use `${var/pattern/subst}` (which can have `subst` left empty, as in, `${string/a*C/}`, or `${var//pattern/subst}` (which works the same way, but replaces *all* instances of `pattern`, not only the first).

---

If your goal is an unanchored, *non-greedy* substring removal, you *could* do it with an extglob, but personally, I'd use a regex written to emulate non-greediness using character classes:

```
re='^(.*)(b[^C]*C)(.*)'

[[ $string =~ $re ]] && result="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"`
```

...whereas the extglob approach would look like:

```
shopt -s extglob
result=${string/b*([^C])C/}
```

Comment: in this case, `${string/b*C/}` stripped away the longest match, and returned `aabc` ... is it possible to somehow, make it strip the shortest match, returning `a123ABCabc`?

Comment: @Renato I'd probably use a regex for that. `re='^(.*)(b[^C]*C)(.*)'; s='abcABC123ABCabc'; [[ $s =~ $re ]] && result="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"`

Comment: Are all of these facilities available in `ksh` too?